# Trying to identify a vehicle, post-war

Tags: vehicle-identification

I am aware this is probably not an ideally-suited SE section for this question, but since Cars seems to have been discontinued I am guessing here is where most car-savvy users will be found.

The problem is to identify the vehicle in the photo. Context is a small South European town, Andorra. Other vehicles in the image (not reproduced here) are not identifiable, with the exception of a GMC CCKW truck, probably from US Army origin and sold as surplus for civilian use after 1945. From the buildings seen, we can also safely assume the image has been taken before 1960 or thereabouts.

From the absence of headlights, I would *think* this is probably the rear part of the vehicle, though in that case the rear window has quite a peculiar shape. The shape of the bumper stops makes me think of a US make, though this is not definite since some European brands followed american styles. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: The vehicle in question]

Here is the full image for context:

[image: Copyright © 2016 Journal Bondia Andorra]

Image taken from [this website](https://www.bondia.ad/vist-i-no-vist/carlemany-anys-50) and is used for illustration purposes only.

Comment: Hi @PAULSTER2 , I didn't include the complete image for copyright reasons. This image would still be covered here in Europe (70-year limit).

Comment: We just need to put where we got it from, then. This would fall under [fair use](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_use).

Comment: (Andorra is small and has just 70.000 residents - yet, it's a state, like Vatican City and Monaco...)

Comment: @sweber Actually we take pride in being slightly older than either of those states in their actual form, with our earliest written Constitution dating from 1278 and a Parlament since 1419. Just sayin' ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a Studebaker Land Cruiser from 1947 to 1952.
[image]

**UPDATE:** Well, I've done a bit more research and basically:

1. Many Studebakers of that era shared extensive styling elements, we
   don't see enough in the original picture to tell for sure which
   specific model it is
2. the main styling variations are length of the trunk, number of panes in the back window, the bumper styling and the tail light grilles, and we really don't see enough of those on the picture to really tell
3. pictures I've found are recent, meaning there's no way to know if those vehicles have been maintained in their original form or if their owners have made some modifications to make them look cool. Tail lights and bumpers are often things people swap from similar model to suit their personal taste. Just look at Japanese cars today, the hottest thing to do is to swap JDM (Japanese Domestic Market) parts (lights, bumpers and skirts) on it to stand out from other cars of the same make and model.
4. Studebakers are from so long ago (the manufacturer disappeared from the auto world 60 years ago), pictures floating around the internet today cannot be relied upon to be labelled properly in terms of specific trim levels.

Comment: It does look very similar indeed. The only difference I can see are the bumper stops, not quite the same shape, and the tail light grilles. Pretty close, though.

Comment: Fair enough. Though slightly incomplete, I am accepting this reply as the best we will get. IMHO, the car could very well be a 1947 Studebacker Champion, as seen here http://www.flickriver.com/photos/jarviseye/2384077210/ , but this should be seen merely as a best guess.

Answer (score 0):

Studebaker, about 1950 , not the Starlight coupe - which had wraparound rear window. Flat head 6 ,so no interest to me.

Comment: Studebakers, especially this model, had V8's starting in 1951.